# convert html table and divs into line breaks in java

Tags: java

Given a chunk of HTML that displays data nicely in  and , how can I remove all the html tags and append text originally wrapped in td, div with a linebreak in Java?

Basically it would be an attempt to convert html into regular text in the common sense.

Comment: simply replace those tags with line breaks(hint : String.replace)

Comment: @Abu: there are opening and closing tags, I only want to replace one of them preferably the closing tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of something like this ..

```
// input an HTML page
String htmlPage = "<html><body>Hello,</br>World</body></html>";

// convert <br>,<hr>, and <hX> to new-line
String temp = htmlPage.replaceAll("(< *br *>< *br */>|< *br *>|< *br */>|< *hr[^>]*>|< *h[1-6][^>]*/>)","\n");

// remove all tags
String text = temp.replaceAll("<[^>]>","");

System.out.println(text);
```

Should print

```
Hello,
World
```

You can tweak this more, for instance you can replace `<body>` or `<div>` with something like `\n----------------\n` to define some structure ..

Consider the following input

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>alert("this is a test");</script>
    <style>p{ font-family: "Times New Roman"; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div><p>This is the first line<br/>This is the second line</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code

```
// convert <br>,<hr>, and <hX> to new-line
String temp = htmlPage.replaceAll("(< *br *>< *br */>|< *br *>|< *br */>|< *hr[^>]*>|< *h[1-6][^>]*/>)","\n");

// seperate HTML structures
temp = temp.replaceAll("(< *head *>|</? *body *>)","\n================\n");

// seperate HTML structures
temp = temp.replaceAll("(< *div *>|< *script *>|< *style *>)","\n----------------\n");

// get rid of empty lines
temp = temp.replaceAll("\n *\n","");

// remove all tags
String text = temp.replaceAll("<[^>]>","");

System.out.println(text);
```

Should print

```
================
Title
----------------
alert("this is a test");
----------------
p{ font-family: "Times New Roman"; }
================
Test
----------------
This is the first line
This is the second line
================
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

```
Jsoup.parse(htmltext).text();
```

You can find various method in Jsoup

Comment: does this replace the tags in question with newline?

Comment: no this will just give the normal text.You can find in the link

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jsoup][1] for it. It is easy to parse HTML pages using this tool.

You can get the HTML doc and can traverse the elements as mentioned here:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Getting started guide is simple to learn and achieve what you want to do.